# How do you listen for session expiration event in cherrypy?

Tags: python, cherrypy

I've done the setup for session timeout:

`'tools.sessions.timeout': 30
  'tools.sessions.on': True`

Everything works fine, however, I am redirected to the login page only after I refresh the
current page.

Is there a way to listen for the session expiration event and do the redirect automatically when this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use javascript and setTimeout to redirect just before the session times out.

```
<body onload="setTimeout('window.location = \'www.yourdomain.com\';', 1700000);">
```

Hope this helps.

Andrew